# Time complexity of using multiple functions?

Tags: python, function, time-complexity

Say we use 2 functions in one go:

`sorted(list(str_variable))` - Python uses Timsort which has a complexity of NlogN - so then the overall complexity of this becomes: `N^2*logN`

It'd be considered as a function inside a function and so the complexities will get multiplied (`O(N)` for `list()` and `O(NlogN)` for the `sort()`.

But I could have also written:

```
s = list(str_variable)
res = sorted(s)
```

In which case its just `O(N)` using `O(N + NlogN)`?

In both the cases, the string variable is split into individual characters and then sorted - so time taken should be the same.

Comment: that's not how it works. first, `list(str_variable)` is executed and then `sorted( answer ) ` is executed, essentially, both of the functions above should take same amount of time.

Comment: you can try : `import time; start_time = time.time(); <your code>; print( time.time() - start_time)` to see the difference, i'd bet the first one is faster. :)

Comment: I understand they would both take about the same time because logically I understand they are both getting executed. Can you explain using the the big o complexities? Thats the part I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Internally, they are being executed as you have shown in your second execution. So your 2nd Big O notation is correct.

Comment: Your first assumption Is wrong.. there is no difference between the two...

Comment: Basically every single one of your assumptions is wrong, not just the first one. The overall complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: @MoB. - can you explain how?

Comment: @user2816215 Sure, I added an answer - hope that clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nested function calls, their complexities **do not** multiply.

Let's say your call is

```
f(g(N))
```

And the time complexities of `f` and `g` on inputs of size `N` are `F(N)` and `G(N)`, respectively. Then the total time complexity is

```
G(N) + F(size(g(N))
```

In your example, `f` is `sorted` and `g` is `list`, so we have the following:

```
F(N) ∈ O(N log N)
G(N) ∈ O(N)
size(g(str_variable)) = N
```

So the total complexity is

```
  G(N) + F(size(g(N))
∈ O(N) + O(N log N)
= O(N log N)    since O(N) ⊂ O(N log N)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works, first, `list(str_variable)` is executed and then `sorted(answer)` is executed, essentially, both of the functions above should take the same amount of time.

Internally, it's being executed as you have shown in your 2nd code snippet, so you can just use the same notations.

You can try and check it like this too:

```
import time
now = time.time()
sorted(list(str_variable))
print(time.time() - now )


now = time.time()
s = list(str_variable)
res = sorted(s)
print(time.time() -now)
```

I'm willing to bet the first one runs faster